# "Parameter Operation is missing" when fetching Amazon book information

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to consume the following service:

```
 file_get_contents(http://webservices.amazon.es/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[MYACCESSKEY]&amp;AssociateTag=[MYTAG]&amp;BrowseNode=&amp;ItemPage=1&amp;Keywords=Book&amp;Operation=ItemSearch&amp;ResponseGroup=BrowseNodes%2CEditorialReview%2CImages%2CItemAttributes%2CItemIds%2CSalesRank%2CAlternateVersions&amp;SearchIndex=Books&amp;Service=AWSECommerceService&amp;Sort=salesrank&amp;Timestamp=2017-08-01T17%3A02%3A58Z&amp;Version=2015-10-01&amp;Signature=XI23CQHWPRTChJ%2F6Mheajw4OBfAm%2BvhdoGlHK0ap1II%3D);
```

it gives me "Parameter Operation is missing." but there it is Operation=ItemSearch

Comment: Do you actually have `&amp;` in the url or is that from a bad copy/paste? Those should just be `&` or all the names in your query are really preceeded with the `amp;` like `amp;Operation`. The html entities are fine when dealing with client side links in html, php won't convert them back.

Comment: Did this come from a program generating it?